# how to show that this prime ideal is minimal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Consider the following ring $$A=\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{(xy,xz)}.$$ I want to show that the prime ideal $$(x+(xy,xz))$$ is minimal.

My idea was to consider an ideal $I$ such that $$(xy,xz)\subset I \subset (x)$$ and prove that $I=(x)$. My problem is: I don't know how to prove that $x \in I$. I'm very thankful for every advice on how to procced.

Comment: You have forgotten the key property that $I$ is a prime ideal. If $I$ was allowed to be non-prime, it wouldn't be true. $I=(x^2,xy,xz)$ works, for example.

Comment: yes, this was my mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $I$ prime ideal such that $$(xy, yz) \subset I \subset (x).$$

In particular, $$xy, yz \in I.$$

If $x \notin I$ then $y, z \in I,$ since $I$ is prime ideal. Then $$y, z \in (x),$$ that is impossible.

Then $$x \in I \text{ and } (x) \subset I.$$

Therefore $I = (x).$